# how to make this function periodic in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, function, math, simulink

I have wrote this code in MATLAB editor and want this function to be periodic (period = 0.8s)

```
HR=75;

E_max=2.0;

E_min=0.06;

t_c=60/HR;

T_max=0.2+0.15*t_c;

t=0:0.0001:t_c;

t_n=t/T_max;

E_n=1.55*(((t_n/0.7).^1.9)./(1+(t_n/0.7).^1.9)).*(1./(1+(t_n/1.17).^21.9));

E=(E_max-E_min)*E_n+E_min;

plot(t,E)
```

I want to use the function in simulink as a voltage source. so i do not need a point but the whole function. so I need a function that takes the overall time (for example 20 secs) and gives the output CONTINUSELY (like a Sin function).

the function and it's shape is:
http://tinypic.com/r/2641a1s/8

Comment: 1) What is your function? The code is very confusing. 2) How do you want to define the periodicy? Seems the function value at 0.8 and 0 are not equal, simple repeating does not seem to be the right option?

Comment: if you just copy and paste this code in your editor and run it you will see that the function values at 0.8 and 0 are equal!!!!!!!!! and what do you mean how i want to make it periodic? by each way it will be periodic!!!! and i think this is so clear that my function is E_n=1.55*(((t_n/0.7).^1.9)./(1+(t_n/0.7).^1.9)).*(1./(1+(t_n/1.17).^21.9)).

Comment: I don't know what you are doing, but I added a `plot(t_n,E)` at the end and both values are not equal. Probably I simply plotted the wrong data, so EXPLAIN your code!

Comment: t_n is t/T_max so you have to plot this: plot(t,E)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your data in the MATLAB base workspace by running your code in MATLAB before running your Simulink model.  Then use the [Repeating Sequence](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/repeatingsequence.html) Block.  Use your variable t as the Time Values and E as the Output Values.  You'll also need to make sure that the maximum step size that the solver takes is min(diff(t)), which in the case of your data is 0.0001.

[image]

Comment: Put the block into your model; double click on the block to open its dialog; in the edit box that says Time Values put the name of your time variable, t; in the edit box that says Output Values out the name of your signal valiable, E.  That's a very fundamental thing to able to do in Simulink -- it sounds like you need to look at the first chapter of the [User Guide](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/gs/create-a-simple-model.html) that gives examples of how to construct basic models.

Answer (score 0):

Well you are confusing the Matlab vector and a function

The function gives a value for any query in the domain of the function.
i.e. if the domain is [-1,2] then f(x) where x in [-1,2] should give and only give one value. such as y = 3x + 2.

## If you want `The function` then you should make the script into a function.

`cardiac.m`

```
function y = cardiac(x,cropPeriod,period)
    t_n = mod(x*cropPeriod/period,cropPeriod); 
    y=1.55*(((t_n/0.7).^1.9)./(1+(t_n/0.7).^1.9)).*(1./(1+(t_n/1.17).^21.9));
end
```

Then, save the file as `cardiac.m` and will give you the function.
And call the function as `cardiac(x,0.8)` then this will give you the value you want

`demo.m`

```
t = 0:0.01:10;  % choose arbitrary range.
p = 0.8;        % period
cropPeriod = 4; % explained below
y = cardiac(t,cropPeriod,p);
plot(t,y);
```

It is clear that the equation given in http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=j75jzk&s=8#.U7iH43VdXJ8 is different from the plot on the image. Since I don't know the period of the function, you can simply choose appropriate number `cropPeriod` until you are satisfied.

#### Example Plot

[image: Periodic plot]

## If you just want to make it to have period `p`

MATLAB plot is nothing but a series of data point. when you call `plot(t,E)`, MATLAB plots a points in position (t(1),E(1)) and (t(2),E(2)) ... Thus, if you want to scale it just type

```
plot(p * t,E);
xlabel('sec(s)'); % Give x axis label
ylabel('E(t)')
```

where `p = 0.8`

Comment: Thanks for answer. I want to use the function in simulink as a voltage source. so i do not need a point but the whole function. so i need a function that takes the overall time (for example 20 secs) and gives the output CONTINUSELY.

Comment: @user3806398, the first implementation is a mathematical function, which means that it gives a value for any input which again, means it gives output CONTINUOUSLY.

Comment: Ah, I found out that the equation given in the url http://tinypic.com/r/2641a1s/8 does not have period 1. I don't think the plot was generated using that equation. To amend, I added additional variable `cropPeriod` to regulate the function shape